# How to simulate carriage return (HEX 0A) in ASCII or normal text?

Tags: ascii, hex

i am required to simulate a carriage return (0A) to save into the database from a web application so that i can prove that the system is not cleaning data causing some issues, this needs to be entered in the browser as a plain text, are we able to do this?

Comment: 0A is a line feed. 0D is a carriage return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but here's an article that uses `CHAR()` function in SQL query http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx

```
insert into mytable(mytext) values('Dear Sir:' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'This is')
```

Line feed `char(10)`

Carriage return `char(13)`

Comment: Thanks, i also found this, as i am using Oracle DBMS http://www.ispirer.com/doc/sqlways/Output/SQLWays-1-071.html

Comment: This was not what OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Line feed char(10) is correct

Carriage return char(13) is giving issues.

Answer (score 0):

From this question: [What character represents a new line in a text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217101/what-character-represents-a-new-line-in-a-text-area)

> By HTML specifications, browsers are required to canonicalize line
>   breaks in user input to CR LF (\r\n).

Hence, you can't insert any other style of newline through a browser.