# ENTER converted from \n to \r\n on POST

Tags: javascript, html, http, post, http-post

I have this simple test page saved as page1.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function submitForm() {
        alert(escape(document.myform.mytextarea.value));
        return true;
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form name="myform" action="page2.html" method="post" onsubmit="javascript:return submitForm();">
      <textarea name="mytextarea">xxxyyy</textarea>

      <input type="submit" value="submitForm">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this page saved as page2.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    Page2.html
  </body>
</html>
```

I open page1.html under Firefox (I think version has no importance, but it is 18.0. And same problem with Chrome or IE 10.0).
Before I click the submitForm button, I hit one ENTER between values "xxx" and "yyy" like this.

[image: HTML Form]

When I click the submitForm button, the alert shows one character between "xxx" and "yyy" which is the \n encoded as "%0A".

[image: Javascript Alert]

If I have a look into Firebug of what is posted, I can see two characters which are "\r\n" encoded as "%0D%0A".

[image: Firebug POST]

Can you explain why \n is transformed to \r\n on POST and how to prevent that ?
I minimized my problem, but it's really problematic for me.

I could test this under Safari on MAC OS, and I also get %0D%0A on POST.

Under IE 8.0 and before, Javascript alerts %0D%0A and I get %0D%0A on POST, so IE 8.0 and before does not behave the same.

Comment: Depending on your operating sistem, new-line character might be represented with just "\n" or with both "\r" and "\n", although that doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: The ECMA script standard says "\n for newline", and alert is ECMA script. It is POST that uses the "real" data, which, on your windows box, is "\r\n", while it is "\r" on a Macbook or "\n" on a Linux box.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1:

in c#:

```
string value = Request.Params["txtValue"].replace("\r\n","\n");
```

### Solution 2:

Or you can add hidden field like:

```
<input id="txtValue" type="textarea" />
<input id="hiddenTxtValue" type="hidden"/>
```

and set his value with `encodeUriComponent`:

```
$('#hiddenTxtValue').val(encodeUriComponent($('#txtValue').val()));
```

in c#:

```
string value = Request.Params["hiddenTxtValue"];
```

Answer (score 1):

New line characters are treated differently for different Operating Systems.

\r = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character in Unix

\n = LF (Line Feed) // Used as a new line character in Mac OS

\r\n = CR + LF // Used as a new line character in Windows

As far as the data in text-area is concerned. When the form is submitted the text-area contents are url-encoded and as per the [HTML Spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1):

> Line breaks, as in multi-line text field values, are represented as CR LF pairs, i.e. `%0D%0A'.

I found a relevant [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217101/what-character-represents-a-new-line-in-a-text-area) that addresses a similar issue with line breaks and cross-platform compatibility.

As far as your problem is concerned if you want new lines to be treated uniformly, you could do a simple regex replace in the contents of your text area to take care of the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your informations, I wrote this function to count the "submitted" length of my textarea on any browser :

```
function getFormURLEncodedLength(myValue) {
  return myValue.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g, '\r\n').length;
}
```