# Javascript - break in textarea but not in paragraph

Tags: javascript, qr-code, line-breaks, vcf-vcard

I have a question:

I have a QR Code Scanner which gets a VCard. Im getting back the following String:
*BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:2.1 FN:John Doe N:doe;john END:VCARD*

The problem is the following: When putting this Information (via Javascript) in a textarea or just dump it to an alert winow, the information has breaks in between, looking like this:

*BEGIN:VCARD 

VERSION:2.1 

FN:John Doe 

.

.

.*

But when putting this information into a paragraph (`<p></p>`), it has no breaks in it and it's just a plain string.

The question is now, can I put those breaks into the paragraph as well or can I insert another sign or anything else in between the attributes?

I thought about just splitting the string on blanks, but it's not working because e.g. `FN` itself contains blanks as wel...

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**
Unfortunatelly, all 3 advices don't work..

What I have now is the following:

```
 function writeqrcodecontent(){
            var textfeld = document.getElementById("inhaltvonqrcode");
            var wert = $.scriptcam.getBarCode();
            //wert.split('\n').join('<br/>');
            //wert.replace("\n", "<br>");
            //wert.replace(/\n/g,'<br>');
            textfeld.innerHTML = wert;
            textfeld.style.display="block";
        }
```

But as said, all three commented out lines do not work, everything is still displayed in one line.

The paragraph is defined with:

```
 <p id="inhaltvonqrcode" style="display:none; clear:both;"></p
```

I understand your ideas but I don't understand why it's not working...

By the way, what I also tried is something like `wert.split('\n').join('#');` to see, if it's really the break or it's just not working, but this doesn't work as well, so the text just seems to have no `\n` in it..

**EDIT 2**

It's working now, I neeeded to do both steps in one step, so not

```
var wert = $.scriptcam.getBarCode();
wert.split('\n').join('<br/>');
```

but

```
var wert = ($.scriptcam.getBarCode()).split('\n').join('<br/>');
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The textarea is probably using `\n` for new lines. For HTML you need to make them `<br />`.

Comment: Just a note that this is [dependent on environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217101/what-character-represents-a-new-line-in-a-text-area).

Answer (score 2):

The string you get back likely contains newline characters `\n`. To get them to display with the newlines intact in HTML, you can either wrap everything returned with  `<pre></pre>` in your HTML. Or split on newline `\n` and replace it with `<br />`.

```
text.split('\n').join('<br />')
```

Comment: Just a note that this is [dependent on environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217101/what-character-represents-a-new-line-in-a-text-area).

Comment: Fortunately that slight difference shouldn't have any effect in this case. (`\r\n` vs `\n`)

Answer (score 1):

`text.replace(/\n/g,'<br>');`

this line will replace all lines with `<br />`

Answer (score 0):

Your barcode reader is reading the vCard with \n newline, however the pure html this newline is ignored.

in Javascript you can just use something like

```
someText.replace("\n", "<br>");
```

and it will do what you want. In php its the nl2br function