# What is the value of a blank line in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently writing a function that would check for the value of each line in a textarea and output the results in another textarea.

My problem now is that I don't know the value of a blank line in a text area, I've tried "", /\W/, undefined, and null, and none of those seem to work. This is what I have right now:

```
function check(){
            var textAreaValue= $("textarea#minCheck").val();
            var valueArray= $("textarea#minCheck").val().split("\n");
            var parsedArray=[];

            for(i=0; i<valueArray.length;i++){
                if(valueArray[i]==/\W/){
                    parsedArray.push(valueArray[i] + "|blank");
                }else if(valueArray[i]>=0 && valueArray[i]<=999){
                    parsedArray.push(valueArray[i] + "|" + "brand1");
                }else if(valueArray[i]>=1000 && valueArray[i]<=1999){
                    parsedArray.push(valueArray[i] + "|" + "brand2");
                }else if(valueArray[i]>=2000 && valueArray[i]<=2999){
                    parsedArray.push(valueArray[i] + "|" + "brand3");
                }else if(valueArray[i]>=3000 && valueArray[i]<=3999){
                    parsedArray.push(valueArray[i] + "|" + "brand4");
                }else{
                    parsedArray.push(valueArray[i]+"|invalid");
                }
            }

            $("textarea#minParsed").val(parsedArray.join("\n"));
        }
```

For now, it gives me "|brand1" when a blank line is checked.

Comment: `valueArray[i]==/\W/`  won't check if the content of `valueArray[i]` matches the regexp `/\W/`. It will compare the two objects, but because the `valueArray[i]`  will be a string and the `/\W/` and `RegExp` this will never be true. You would need to use the [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function of a RegExp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this : trim the value of line and check with empty space `if(valueArray[i].trim()==""){`, see below code

```
     function check(){
        var textAreaValue= $("textarea#minCheck").val();
        var valueArray= $("textarea#minCheck").val().split("\n");
        var parsedArray=[];

        for(i=0; i<valueArray.length;i++){
            if(valueArray[i].trim()==""){
                parsedArray.push(valueArray[i] + "|blank");
            }else if(valueArray[i]>=0 && valueArray[i]<=999){
                parsedArray.push(valueArray[i] + "|" + "brand1");
            }else if(valueArray[i]>=1000 && valueArray[i]<=1999){
                parsedArray.push(valueArray[i] + "|" + "brand2");
            }else if(valueArray[i]>=2000 && valueArray[i]<=2999){
                parsedArray.push(valueArray[i] + "|" + "brand3");
            }else if(valueArray[i]>=3000 && valueArray[i]<=3999){
                parsedArray.push(valueArray[i] + "|" + "brand4");
            }else{
                parsedArray.push(valueArray[i]+"|invalid");
            }
        }

        $("textarea#minParsed").val(parsedArray.join("\n"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check blank line using this regex expression :  /^\s*\n/gm and for Mac line endings use: /^\s*[\r\n]/gm

Comment: The `[\r\n]` is not wrong, but the explanation. The Line endings of OS X and Linux is `\n`. On windows it is `\r`. Only for MacOS prior to OS X it was  `\r\n`, but `[\r\n]` would not match those because `[\r\n]`  is either  `\r` or `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to use regular expression metacharacters (`\W`) without a Regexp call.

The literal value is probably `\r\n` (CR+LF) so if you split on `\n` you are left with `\r`

Try splitting on `\r\n` and then check for empty string `""`

The HTML5 standard actually changes some things related to this, though I don't know what practical impact it has had in actual browser implementations. I think the HTML5 standard says that the client-side API could see any combination (CR, LF, or CR+LF), since the user is allowed to edit the content.

A better answer is here that describes the scenarios:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14217315/257090