# Handle Html tags in input area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5

Need to allow/disallow some certain html tags in js side.
Developing a laravel project where in some input box need to consider certain html elements.

Can be done using string replace function but will take much more time to maintain the list of not allowable items.like the following

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
 }
```

Again the allowed html tag list can also be small so if just want to allow 
then the unsafe list will be huge.

I can also do it in server side but cant get any proper source for that.

**It will be so helpful if someone can just suggest me what would be the best way for maintaining this allow/disallow html tag list?**

Answer (score 1):

Never use clientside JS to escape anything. Adversaries can easily block the execution of your JS file and bypass it.

Server side [prepared statements](http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries) are industry standard for what you want.

Prepared statements treat user inputs as non-executable strings that have no effect on any queries you make using these inputs (ie SQL Injections).

Comment: Yes for sql injection we have used your suggested array binding way. But for certain input field like friend's comment on status need to allow only <br> but not any other tag like <script> or other tags. server side has html purifier but not familiar with it

Comment: To my knowledge things like `tabs` and `newlines` are encoded into strings, thus are not represented in their native `<html>` tags. IE newlines are encoded as ` \r\n` See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217101/what-character-represents-a-new-line-in-a-text-area

Comment: yeah but you can also inject scripts with some alert or something similar. Those will create problem if not taken care of

Comment: Persistent injections have to go through the server, which is protected by prepared statements. Alerts would only affect the attacker and no one else.

Answer (score 0):

So finally what i decided is using htmlpurifier

https://github.com/mewebstudio/purifier

So in server side we can customize which page will allow which tag using this