# PHP form generates windows line-breaks under linux

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, firefox, newline

I have a simple PHP form in which text with line breaks has **Windows line breaks** (`\r\n`) instead of linux line breaks (`\n`). Client and server are both the same machine **running Ubuntu**.

The PHP script:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <textarea name="q"><?= htmlentities(@$_REQUEST['q']); ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<hr />
<?= urlencode(@$_REQUEST['q']); ?>
```

The test:

- focus textarea
- press ENTER on keyboard
- click submit button with mouse

Expected result:

- `%0A`

Actual result:

- `%0D%0A`

System environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC which is also the scripts host and
- Firefox 50.1.0 or Chromium 55.0.2883.87, and
- PHP 7.0.8

Which software part is responsible for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14217315/1583522