# Javascript regex to match more than one line break

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a javascript regex that will not allow more than one line break or carriage return. One line break is OK, more than one should not be permitted. I have this which does not allow any, but I'm unable to modify it to allow only one line break?

`^[^\n\r]*$`

Comment: Why don't you just replace multiple with one instead of throwing an error?

Comment: Do some research on regular expressions; especially [quantifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers). See if you can figure it out yourself.

Comment: Do you want to disallow more than 1 consecutive line breaks or more than 1 line breaks anywhere?

Comment: disallow more than 1 consecutive line break

Comment: Then just look for `/(?:\r?\n){2}/` for detecting 2 consecutive line breaks

Comment: Are you just trying to detect if a string value has more than one CRLF? Also, is this from text entered in a browser? All line endings should be CRLF (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217101/what-character-represents-a-new-line-in-a-text-area). A simple `str.indexOf()` will do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` to text for multiple `\n` and throw an alert, like so:

```js
var text = "hello\nworld\n\nmore here\n"

if (text.match(/\n[\n]+/g)){
  alert("Error mulitple new lines");  
}
```

You may want to first remove the `\r` or alter the above to also match `\r` also.

Comment: Ideally what I'm looking for is a regex to match the condition of more than one line break, where I will trigger an error message on form submission instead of a replace.

Comment: i've updated the code and placed an `alert` where you will need to tie into your form errors.

Comment: There's no need to put it inside `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

The round brackets constitute a group. Your group is "\n\r", which should not be multiple. So you use a "+", that constitute 1 or more. In following case it will replace every multiple "\n\r" with "\n\r\" and every single "\n\r" with it.

```js
var multiple = "hello\n\r\n\rworld\n\r!"

var single = multiple.replace(/(\n\r)+/g, "\\n\\r");
console.log(single);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for ^[\n\r]* look for ^\n\r[\n\r]*

```
var regpat = /^(\n\r)[\n\r]*/;
var str = "\n\r\n\r";
str.replace(re, '$1');
```