# How to validate the years in a drop-down box using protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am validating a drop down box that contains years.

Below is my code to validate the drop-down box. However protractor still returns an error message for that line of code.  I am not sure why its returning an error message.

```
var EachYear = element.all(by.id("Years"));               
expect(EachYear.getText()).toBe(['Year\n2017\n2018\n2019\n2020\n2021\n2022\n2023']);
```

### Error message

> Expected [ 'Year 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023' ] to be [ 'Year 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023' ].✗

Comment: Do you actually care about the format of this string of bytes, or do you care that the earliest year available is the current year, that there are 7 options, and that the list is consecutive and in ascending order, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

New line character in browsers is CR LF(`\r\n`), not `\n`.
Changing your code like below can fix the problem.

```
expect(EachYear.getText()).toBe(['Year\r\n2017\r\n2018\r\n2019\r\n2020\r\n2021\r\n2022\r\n2023']);
```

Reference: [What character represents a new line in a text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217101/what-character-represents-a-new-line-in-a-text-area)