# Why is PHP_EOL not working when nl2br works fine

Tags: php, exploded

I copy the following string from a web page:

```
Reservation No.:    218662
Play Date:  Saturday - 4/11/2020
Course:     Truman  352-750-2374
```

I want to break on CRLF and create three lines in my array.  There is a CRLF (0D 0A) after 2374 and 2020

I have tried

```
$lines = explode ("/n",$this->reservation);
$lines = explode ("/r/n",$this->reservation);
$lines = explode ("chr(10)",$this->reservation);
$lines = explode (chr(13.chr(10),$this->reservation);
$lines = explode (PHP_EOL,$this->reservation);
```

and nothing works.

However nl2br does display the string properly.

So, it seems the nl2br is recognizing the line breaks in the source string but explode is not.

What am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: Because you're displaying the output on a web page. Unless you're outputting to a `<pre>` element, text is automatically re-formatted.

Comment: `/n` and `/r` should be `\n` and `\r`

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is the end-of-line sequence on the server, which might not be the same as the client.

Comment: I'm not trying to output the strings.  I want them place in an array yet no matter what I do, the array contains only one string, the original string.

Comment: `explode("\n", $this->reservation)` should work.

Comment: For reasons I can't explain...
$lines = explode(chr(13), $this->reservation);  works fine
$lines = explode("\n", $this->reservation); fails

Comment: `chr(13) == "\r", chr(10) == "\n"`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217101/what-character-represents-a-new-line-in-a-text-area

Comment: Is this coming from a `<textarea>` input field, or are you parsing HTML?

Comment: It is coming from a textarea into which I have pasted  what I copied from a web page.  In every case, it seems that the text includes the sequence 0A 0D.