# Do web forms have a standard for line breaks?

Tags: html, sql, postgresql, ascii

If I have a `<textarea>` element and I hit the enter key, is what represents the line break going to matter depending on things like browser, OS, programming language, etc. or will it always use a CRLF pair?

I tested using Python Firefox and Chrome, I wrote data to a Postgres database using a web form and it inserted the data like
`"Line1\r\nLine2\r\nLine3\r\nLine4"` and it did that for Chrome and Firefox.

But I'm curious if this will always be the case? Are web forms always going to write the CRLF or are there times the non printable characters will be different? So a `\n` instead of `\r\n`?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217101/what-character-represents-a-new-line-in-a-text-area

Comment: \r\n all day everyday!!!! Thanks.