# Monospace ASCII art in non verbatim formatting on github

Tags: html, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to:

- form an ASCII art directory structure (similar to this [fastlane snippet](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/1895688)) in markdown (specifically on github comments).
  But it has to have hyperlinks in it, so, the usual `` `verbatim` `` will not work. ∴ I am looking for some way to format normal markdown text in the `monospace` font-family and give explicit spaces and explicit line breaks to preserve the structure.

I have found solutions for:

- **`monospace`**: the [html tag teletype](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=monospace+tag+in+html&t=vivaldi&ia=web) `tt` or `code` works
- **explicit space**: the [non-breaking space](https://newbedev.com/how-do-i-ensure-that-whitespace-is-preserved-in-markdown) `&nbps;` seems good alternate

  - to insert it directly as  : use <kbd>alt + 255</kbd> on windows
  - for records: `&Tab;` doesn't work

---

Remains:

- how to elegantly give **explicit line breaks**
- (any other solution/advice/suggestion is welcome too)

Where do I stand:

- Using `<tt>...</tt>` per line works in preserving line breaks, but due to the inherent inline nature it doesnt render good
- Using `<tt>...</tt>` at block level (similar to [recommended usage of `details` tag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html)) gives a super awesome rendering, but doesnt provide any way to insert single line breaks (i think t's called soft break?) ...
- ... none work among these: `/ <enter>` ; `<br/>` ; `&NewLine;` ; `&#13;&#10;` (CRLF). I found these via [Whitespace_character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) article referred in [mailtrap blog on nbsp](https://mailtrap.io/blog/nbsp/#Other-spaces-available-in-HTML); and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582563/8395964)
- ... 2 `<enters>` provides 2 line breaks in render too

[image: Render Preview Screenshot]

Sources of trials:

```markdown
<tt>/</tt>
<tt>├── fastlane</tt>
<tt>└── fastlane</tt>
<tt>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;├── [changelog]</tt>
<tt>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;│&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;├ ...</tt>
<tt>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;│&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;├ ...</tt>

[changelog]: https://example.com
```

```markdown
<tt>

/

├── fastlane \
└── fastlane <br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;├── [changelog] &NewLine;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;│&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;├ ... &#13;&#10;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;│&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;├ ...

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;│&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;├ ...

</tt>

[changelog]: https://example.com
```

---

**Addendum:**

- Duplicate search: [monospace but not verbatim](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=monospace+but+not+verbatim)
- I was reading the GitHub flavored Markdown [gfm/#example-141](https://github.github.com/gfm/#example-141) and that example obviously didn't work in comments, so... I dont't know what spec sheet do github comments follow.
- Some useful pages on this topic: [w3s/html_entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) ; [html-escape-chars](https://mateam.net/html-escape-characters/) ; [named-chars](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html#named-character-references) via [html.com](https://html.com/character-codes/) ;

Comment: i tried, and the `<br/` tag inside `<tt></tt>` works in the vscodium's markdown preview. so, the issue is with github or other things not supporting this combination of these tags in markdown.